# PHP function with unlimited number of parameters

Tags: php, arguments

How do I write a function that can accept unlimited number of parameters?

What am trying to do is create a function within a class that wraps the following:

```
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

Comment: you can't do it without toilsome efforts. I'd suggest either build a query usual way, or move to PDO if you want native prepared statements at any cost. They have bindValue, mind you

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately PDO appears to be overkill, with even more effort and boilerplate, compared to just writing my own simple stuff.

Comment: For the simple stuff you can use a lib from my userinfo. It's real simple though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above suggests are all good, but I don't think they will be suitable for your situation.

```
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

If you want to wrap this function, you will need to pass *references* to the original argument variables to the bind_param function. I don't think func_get_args() gives you this, it gives you values instead. Thus it won't be possible to use these to pass to the parent function. I battled with a similar issue when trying to extend mysqli_stmt and never came to satisfactory solution.

This is not really an answer to your question I'm afraid, just a warning that other arguments may not work in your particular application of arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: Indeed. Last time I checked (1+ year ago) there was no way to wrap/extend `bind_param()` because `func_get_args()` won't return references.

Answer (score 24):

Have you taken a look at [func_get_args](http://php.net/func_get_args), [func_get_arg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php) and [func_num_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)

So for example:

```
function foo(){
    if ( func_num_args() > 0 ){
        var_dump(func_get_args());
    }
}
```

or:

```
function bind_param(){
    if ( func_num_args() <= 1 ){
        return false; //not enough args
    }
    $format = func_get_arg(0)
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1)

    //etc
}
```

**EDIT**
Regarding Ewan Todds comment:
I don't have any knowlege of the base API you are creating the wrapper for, but another alternative may be to do something with chaining functions so your resulting interface looks something like:

```
$var->bind()->bindString($code)
            ->bindString($language)
            ->bindString($official)
            ->bindDecimal($percent);
```

Which I would prefer over the use of func_get_args as the code is probably more readable and more importantly less likely to cause errors due to the the lack of a format variable.

Comment: I use func_get_args from time to time. It suffers from making it difficult see at a glance what the method's inputs are. Plus, it introduces a block of butt ugly syntax into your code. I would recommend this approach only as a last resort. Prefer the Parameter Object refactoring.

Comment: I agree with you that it is a bad way of doing variable arguments. I have added an alternative idea to my answer

Comment: I like the "chaining functions" proposal better than func_get_args.  I know this design as a FLUENT interface.  It is accomplished by having  bindString(), bindDecimal() etc. do "return $this;" as their last line.  The FLUENT interface is a great option for cetain types of factory.

Answer (score 24):

Previously you should have used `func_get_args()`, but in the **php 5.6**, you can use [... operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking).

So for example you can write the function which returns you a sum of all the numbers, sent to the function:

```
function bind_param(...$params){
   var_dump($params);
}
```

Your `params` is actually an array of all elements.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using PHP 5.6 or later version, argument lists may include the **`...`** token to denote that the function accepts a variable number of arguments. The arguments will be passed into the given variable as an array; Simply  Using **`...`** you can access unlimited variable arguments.

**for example:**

```
<?php
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $sum += $n;
    }
    return $sum ;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
?>
```

If you are using **PHP version <= 5.5** then you can access unlimited parameterusing the [func_num_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php), [func_get_arg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php), and [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) functions.

**For example:**

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs \n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`func_get_args()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php):

```
function my_func() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  foreach ($args as $arg) {
    echo "Arg: $arg\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the parameters are not set, and are then passed by reference, to be set inside the function. func_get_args tries to access the unset variable which throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

At 5 parameters, this design is starting to exhibit the AntiPattern "[Too Many Parameters](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TooManyParameters)".  This suggests the refactoring called [Parameter Object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject), an object or structure with data members representing the arguments to be passed in.  However, avoid making it a [Magic Container](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MagicContainer).

See also [Introduce Parameter Object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) refactoring at refactoring.com.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called [func_get_args()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) which is an array of all arguments passed to the function.

Example from PHP.net

```
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```

The above example will output:

Number of arguments: 3
Second argument is: 2
Argument 0 is: 1
Argument 1 is: 2
Argument 2 is: 3

Answer (score 0):

The answers with func_get_args() will work fine for non-reference parameters.
However, there's a trick to getting passed-by-reference parameters to work.
Also, it's not technically a function which accepts *unlimited* parameters, but simply some arbitrarily large number, say one hundred.

What you can do, is define a function which takes a large number of arguments, and have them default to null.
Then, inside that function, append each non-null reference to an array, which would then be used to call *bind_param()* using *call_user_func_array()*.

```
function my_bind_param(&$stmt, $types, &$arg1, &$arg2 = null, &$arg3 = null, ...)
{
    $vars = array($types);
    $vars[] = $arg1;

    if ($arg2 != null)
        $vars[] = &$arg2;
    if ($arg3 != null)
        $vars[] = &$arg3;
    ...

    if (!call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $vars))
    {
        if ($stmt->errno == 0)
            return array(-1, "Unknown error binding parameters.");
        else
            return array(-1, "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
    }

    return array(0, "");
}
```

The real trick is that you don't want to write this thing by hand.
Just make another script which will output the body of this function (everything between the squiggle brackets) as *my_bind_param_body.php*.
Then, just define the header of the function in your main file, and include the body into that function definition.
i.e.

```
function my_bind_param(&$stmt, $types, &$arg1, &$arg2 = null, &$arg3 = null, ...)
{
    return include "my_bind_param_wrapper_body.php";
}
```