# What is the syntax for multiple arguments in PHP?

Tags: php, methods

A simple question:

What is the syntax for creating a function with **unlimited*** arguments in PHP?

Example (ActionScript 3):

```
function multiTrace(...arguments):void
{
    var i:String;
    for each(i in arguments)
        trace(i);
}
```

The goal is to have a function that I can call and list any given amount of stylesheets within, eg:

```
$avian->insertStyles("overall.css", "home.css");
```

**Subject to obvious limitations (RAM, etc).*

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577383/php-function-with-unlimited-number-of-parameters

Comment: @Bing Cheers - had a quick search before I asked but this didn't come up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function multiTrace() 
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    while ($arg = array_shift($args)) {
        echo $arg; 
    }
}
```

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: @Peter Kruithof Also just an example, the while loop is a bit problematic. Think of what happens if one of the given parameters is `0` or `false` (or anything which can be cast to boolean `false`.)

Comment: Marty, you should accept an answer, if it answers your question :) You might also want to look at [`func_num_args()`](http://www.php.net/func_num_args) and [`func_get_arg()`](http://www.php.net/func_get_arg), though `func_get_args()` seems to be the one that's used in most cases. You might also be interested in [default argument values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default), e.g., `function getUerName($userID = null) { }`.

Comment: @Yoshi, good point. I would use `foreach ( $args as $arg ) { }`.

Comment: @binaryLV @Peter Kruithof Yes, if a loop is need that's what I'd use, too.

Comment: @binaryLV There's a minimum time applied to answer acceptance - I know how to use SO. Also, thanks for the additional links.

Answer (score 3):

See

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

```
function testfunction() {
    $arguments = func_get_args();

    var_dump($arguments);
}

testfunction("argument1", "argument2");
```

Result:

```
array
  0 => string 'argument1' (length=9)
  1 => string 'argument2' (length=9)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are after the func_get_args function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php