# PHP function parameters my_func($param='')

Tags: php

I saw some PHP today I don't understand, can anyone explain it to me?

```
function my_func($param='')
{

    if (empty($param))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is the $param variable being assigned an empty string but somehow not being empty inside the function? Is this just a default value?

Comment: PHP function docs: [default argument values](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP function with unlimited number of parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577383/php-function-with-unlimited-number-of-parameters)

Comment: @Shiplu I disagree. That question is a bit different, and it makes no reference to default argument values.

Comment: thanks all, shame I can't accept more than one answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_func("string") //makes $param "string"

my_func() //picks default making $param ''
```

You can have required and optional params like

```
function my_func($param1, $param2='default')
```

You can NOT put optional params behind required params

```
function my_func($param1='', $param2) //gives errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can assign a default value to a param in PHP. You can overwrite it using my_func("None Empty String") for example!

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption was correct; this allows the developer to assign a default value to the parameter.

If the calling code does not pass a parameter value, the function returns false. Otherwise, `$param` is non-empty, and the function returns true.

A potential pitfall with this code is the case of a parameter being passed with an empty value (0, null, etc). The code will return `false` even though a parameter was passed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the variable inside the parenthesis of the function declaration is a default value, and is used so you can call the function like this:

```
echo my_func();
```

Without needing to actually pass a variable to the function at all.