# What is the syntax to define a function taking an arbitrary number of references?

Tags: php, function, syntax, mysqli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP function with unlimited number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577383/php-function-with-unlimited-number-of-parameters)

#### Original Question:

*(Scroll down for conclusions.)*

I'm trying to create a simple wrapper around `mysqli_stmt::bind_param` and `mysqli_stmt::bind_result`.
Basically, call the function, and return some info about any errors received, so I don't have to rewrite these several lines again and again.

Since both of those mysqli functions take their arguments as references instead of copies, I'll need to have my function take its arguments as references.
(It would also force me to rebind every time I called `mysqli_stmt::execute`, if I bound to copies instead of references.)

So, ideally, I'd like to be able to define a function taking an arbitrary number of references, like the mysqli functions themselves do:

```
public function foo(&$var1, &$var2, ...)
{
    ...
}
```

Failing that, I'll need to define a function which takes an array of references.
I know the syntax for taking references is as it appears above.
Is there syntax for arrays of references,

```
public function foo($var[&$i])
{
    ...
}
```

like this?

#### Conclusions / Info for future people trying the same thing:

Basically, you can't define a function which takes an arbitrary number of arguments, which are by reference.
From the answers, comments, and this other question [PHP function with unlimited number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577383/php-function-with-unlimited-number-of-parameters) it looks like an almost impossible task.

A cheap hack, which would technically work, would be to define a function like this one:

```
function foo(&$arg1, &$arg2 = null, &$arg3 = null, ...)
{
    echo $arg1;
    if ($arg2 != null)
        echo br() . $arg2;

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, define a function taking, let's say a hundred arguments, passed by reference, all but the first defaulting to null.
Then, you can call it with any number of of arguments, all passed by reference, from 1-100.
The trick is that you don't want to code this monstrosity yourself; Make a script to generate this function, and stick it in its own *my-horribly-long-function.php* file.